# Reset Form After Submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

I have a react form that calls a graphql mutation when the button is clicked. After the button is clicked and the mutation is completed, the text in the form is still there. So in order to run a new mutation, the user will have to manually remove the text written in the text fields.

Is there any way to automatically reset the text fields once the form is submitted?

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation<DeleteUserReponse>(REMOVE_USER);

  let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<DeleteUserReponse>) => {
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined){
        setIsRemoved(true);
      }})
      .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
        setIsRemoved(false);
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      });
  };

  const initialValues={ email: '' }
  return (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
      <Formik
        //initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
          initialValues={initialValues}
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}>
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: FormEvent) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <div>
              <form
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                  />
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!isValid || !email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </form>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage(isRemoved, errorMessage)}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just set initialValues object outside of component and then assign it as initialValues and also  at the end on onSubmit function.

Comment: How could I set it again after onSubmit? Could you please see the edited code? @zhuber

Answer (score 0):

Try reusing your initial state, something like this:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { email: '' };

export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation<DeleteUserReponse>(REMOVE_USER);

  let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<DeleteUserReponse>) => {
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined){
        setIsRemoved(true);
      }})
      .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
        setIsRemoved(false);
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ ...INITIAL_STATE }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
          actions.setValues({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}>
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: FormEvent) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <div>
              <form
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                  />
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!isValid || !email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </form>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage(isRemoved, errorMessage)}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Although I've also seen `resetForm` method on second parameter of `onSubmit`, but haven't tested it how it works, so you can try that also.

Comment: This compiles but doesn't reset the form on submit. I couldn't find any example for resetForm on onSubmit either :(